# Compilation error Mongo ext PHP 7 via PECL

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework, compilation, debian

I try to install Mongo PHP extension via PECL (for PHP 7.0.5-4+donate.sury.org~xenial+1) by executing

```
sudo pecl install mongo-1.6.11
```

I try to install it this way because my Synfony3 project needs it (to execute composer install and install MongoDB ODM).

All the beginning of the process is well done but at the compilation part I have that error :

```
/tmp/pear/temp/mongo/php_mongo.c:736:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘zend_hash_copy’
   zend_hash_copy(Z_ARRVAL_P(error_doc), Z_ARRVAL_P(document), (copy_ctor_func_t) zval_add_ref, NULL, sizeof(zval *));
```

Can you help me to solve this problem? I run the dev website under Kubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legacy driver (i.e. Mongo) does not work with PHP 7, only new driver (i.e. MongoDB) can be used with new PHP (see [compatibility table](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/#language-compatibility)). Supposing you have meant Doctrine's MongoDB ODM you still can use it, just need to combine new driver with a polyfill for the old one, I would suggest taking a look at [mongo-php-adapter](https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter).

Also you can find some more information in [this ODM blogpost](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2016/02/16/doctrine-mongodb-odm-release-1.0.5.html).